# Change/control checkbox checked state depending on the data resolved from the promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, promise

What I want is when I clicked the checkbox and the resolve data in a promise is false. I want the checkbox to stay its check state to not checked. If the data is true then the checkbox check state is checked.

I have created a simple [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-morning-l6oib?file=/src/App.js) for this. I am using react and mdc component for checkbox. There is no error I just want to control the state of my checkbox.

To be more convenient to you here I post the code here but if you want to play with it I suggest visiting the link.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Checkbox from "@material/react-checkbox";

export default function App() {
  const [verified, setVerified] = useState(false);

  const promisify = () =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const data = false;
      resolve(data);
    });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <div className="simple-demo">
        <Checkbox
          checked={verified}
          onChange={(e) => {
            promisify().then((data) => {
              console.log(data);
              if (data) {
                setVerified(e.target.checked);
              }
            });
          }}
        />
        <label>Verify</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You haven't defined what the specific  problem is with the code shown. What happens, what doesn't happen, what should happen differently, errors etc

Comment: It is already cleared that i want to control the checkstate of the checkbox depending on the data resolved from the promise

Comment: its hard to explain man i am not a native speaker but i try. wait second

Comment: @charlietfl bro i added addtional notes. let me know if you dont get the point i will insert a demo video

Comment: Where's the codesandbox link?

Comment: @bertdida sorry man i edited my question with the link

Comment: There's probably a better way but if you do `setVerified(true);setVerified(false)` in `else` it works

Comment: @charlietfl can you send me a snippets i tried it but still not working

Comment: Use both in the `else`. you only used `setVerified(false)`. It seems to work using both. `} else {  setVerified(true); setVerified(false);  }`

Comment: @charlietfl i understand now your answer. thanks guyz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple mistake,
you have set **verified** in value, but it must be in checked attribute

like this

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Checkbox from "@material/react-checkbox";

export default function App() {
const [verified, setVerified] = useState(false);

const promisify = () =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const data = false;
    resolve(data);
    });

return (
    <div className="App">
    <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
    <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    <div className="simple-demo">
        <Checkbox
        checked={verified}
        onChange={(e) => {
            setVerified(e.target.checked)
            promisify().then((data) => {
            if (data) {
                //Do your action here
            } else {
                setVerified(false);
            }
            console.log(verified)
            });
        }}
        />
        <label>Verify</label>
    </div>
    </div>
);
}
```

Comment: Hi romik i tried it but still not working. I think it is the nature of checkbox? or something

Comment: I have changed in send box, you can test. Thanks.

Comment: did you forked the sand box? can you give me a link